# Vue3 cannot obtain instance of component from another component

Tags: vuejs3, components, this, vue-composition-api

**Vue 3 Composition API**

I have two components A and B
I use the mode script setup
I don't know how to call a function declared in component A into the component B. Please help me.
I want to get the **this** of component A to call a function like in option API

> I tried getInstance().ctx method but i cannot access to any function or variable
> thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { ref, onMounted, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';
//
let $this = getCurrentInstance();

// initialize components based on data attribute selectors
onMounted(() => {
    $this = $this.setupState;
    //and after you can call any function or variables with '$this'
}
```

I found a solution myself in vue 3 composition API methods